# Splash Screen and icons are not appearing in iOS while building ipk at https://build.phonegap.com/apps/*****/builds

Tags: ios, cordova, build, phonegap-build

Hi When I am trying to build ipk with splash screens and icon are not appearing, I am checking it on iphone 5s. the folder structure for zip folder added is as follows. But whenever I build it online and download, after installation its entire web.config is changed

```
--config.xml
--www
  --icons
    --icon-29.png
    --icon-40.png
    --icon-50.png
    --icon-50.png
    --<many more>


  --splash
    --splash_320.png
    --splash_640.png
    --splash_640x.png
    --<many more>

  --index.html
```

Structure of config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.someapp.someappversionCode = " 1 " version= "1.0.0 " >
  <name>Some text</name>
  <description>
     some text
  </description>
  <author email="support@example.com" href="http://example.com">
    Some text
  </author>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser " />
  <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer " />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen " />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device " />
  <content src="www/index.html " />
  <access origin="tel:* " launch-external="yes " />
  <preference name="SplashScreen " value="screen " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash.png " />
  <preference name="phonegap-version " value="3.6.3 " />

  <icon src="www/icons/icon.png " />

  <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-180.png " gap:platform="ios " width="180 " height="180 " />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-60.png " gap:platform="ios " width="60 " height="60 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-120.png " gap:platform="ios " width="120 " height="120 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-76.png " gap:platform="ios " width="76 " height="76 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-152.png " gap:platform="ios " width="152 " height="152 " />

  <!-- Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-29.png " gap:platform="ios " width="29 " height="29 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-58.png " gap:platform="ios " width="58 " height="58 " />

  <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-40.png " gap:platform="ios " width="40 " height="40 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-80.png " gap:platform="ios " width="80 " height="80 " />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-57.png " gap:platform="ios " width="57 " height="57 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-114.png " gap:platform="ios " width="114 " height="114 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-72.png " gap:platform="ios " width="72 " height="72 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-144.png " gap:platform="ios " width="144 " height="144 " />

  <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-29.png " gap:platform="ios " width="29 " height="29 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-58.png " gap:platform="ios " width="58 " height="58 " />

  <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-50.png " gap:platform="ios " width="50 " height="50 " />
  <icon src="www/icons/icon-100.png " gap:platform="ios " width="100 " height="100 " />


  <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_320.png " gap:platform="ios " width="320 " height="480 " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_640.png " gap:platform="ios " width="640 " height="960 " />

  <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_640x.png " gap:platform="ios " width="640 " height="1136 " />

  <!-- iPhone 6 -->
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_750.png " gap:platform="ios " width="750 " height="1334 " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_1242.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1242 " height="2208 " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_2208.png " gap:platform="ios " width="2208 " height="1242 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_768.png " gap:platform="ios " width="768 " height="1024 " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_1024.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1024 " height="768 " />

  <!-- Retina iPad -->
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_1536.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1536 " height="2048 " />
  <gap:splash src="www/splash/splash_2048.png " gap:platform="ios " width="2048 " height="1536 " />
  
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the above issue working, 
I changed my folder structure to

```
--config.xml
--icon-29.png
--icon-40.png
--icon-50.png
--<many more>

--splash
--splash_320.png
--splash_640.png
--splash_640x.png
--<many more>

--index.html
--<other html resources>
```

and changed my config file as follows

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.someapp.someappversionCode = " 1 " version= "1.0.0 " >
  <name>Some text</name>
  <description>
     some text
  </description>
  <author email="support@example.com" href="http://example.com">
    Some text
  </author>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser " />
  <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer " />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen " />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device " />
  <content src="index.html " />
  <access origin="tel:* " launch-external="yes " />
  <preference name="SplashScreen " value="screen " />
  <gap:splash src="splash.png " />
  <preference name="phonegap-version " value="3.6.3 " />

  <icon src="icon.png " />

  <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
  <icon src="icon-180.png " gap:platform="ios " width="180 " height="180 " />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
  <icon src="icon-60.png " gap:platform="ios " width="60 " height="60 " />
  <icon src="icon-120.png " gap:platform="ios " width="120 " height="120 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="icon-76.png " gap:platform="ios " width="76 " height="76 " />
  <icon src="icon-152.png " gap:platform="ios " width="152 " height="152 " />

  <!-- Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="icon-29.png " gap:platform="ios " width="29 " height="29 " />
  <icon src="icon-58.png " gap:platform="ios " width="58 " height="58 " />

  <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
  <icon src="icon-40.png " gap:platform="ios " width="40 " height="40 " />
  <icon src="icon-80.png " gap:platform="ios " width="80 " height="80 " />

  <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
  <icon src="icon-57.png " gap:platform="ios " width="57 " height="57 " />
  <icon src="icon-114.png " gap:platform="ios " width="114 " height="114 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <icon src="icon-72.png " gap:platform="ios " width="72 " height="72 " />
  <icon src="icon-144.png " gap:platform="ios " width="144 " height="144 " />

  <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="icon-29.png " gap:platform="ios " width="29 " height="29 " />
  <icon src="icon-58.png " gap:platform="ios " width="58 " height="58 " />

  <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
  <icon src="icon-50.png " gap:platform="ios " width="50 " height="50 " />
  <icon src="icon-100.png " gap:platform="ios " width="100 " height="100 " />


  <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
  <gap:splash src="splash_320.png " gap:platform="ios " width="320 " height="480 " />
  <gap:splash src="splash_640.png " gap:platform="ios " width="640 " height="960 " />

  <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
  <gap:splash src="splash_640x.png " gap:platform="ios " width="640 " height="1136 " />

  <!-- iPhone 6 -->
  <gap:splash src="splash_750.png " gap:platform="ios " width="750 " height="1334 " />
  <gap:splash src="splash_1242.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1242 " height="2208 " />
  <gap:splash src="splash_2208.png " gap:platform="ios " width="2208 " height="1242 " />

  <!-- iPad -->
  <gap:splash src="splash_768.png " gap:platform="ios " width="768 " height="1024 " />
  <gap:splash src="splash_1024.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1024 " height="768 " />

  <!-- Retina iPad -->
  <gap:splash src="splash_1536.png " gap:platform="ios " width="1536 " height="2048 " />
  <gap:splash src="splash_2048.png " gap:platform="ios " width="2048 " height="1536 " />
  
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `www/` from your paths on *config.xml* if you intend to use it on PhoneGap Build. See the [PGB documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html) where it says

> src: (required) specifies the location of the image file, relative to your www directory

The main part is the *relative to your www directory* which means that you are now trying to access folder `www/www/icons/`.

Comment: I removed that still it's not working as expected, unable to see splash screen. Moreover the config.xml becomes meaningless. the config.xml in ipk shows
<name> Hello Cordova </name><description> A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event. </description><author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org"> Apache Cordova Team </author>

but plugin info is there as same as my original config.xml

Comment: Well, do the plugins (inappbrowser, email composer, etc.) get loaded properly on PGB (check the plugins tab on your app on PGB). Also you have odd space inside every attributes value such as *src="www/splash/splash.png "*. There should be no space after *.png*.

Comment: I've answered my question, I don't know where the problem was but removing the folder structure helped me after number of builds.

Comment: @AjaySuwalka: It works perfectly okay for me and others with the relative paths.

Comment: I am not sure but it didn't work for me so I removed the path information and kept them in root itself